Why can't I install wine32 on Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish)
Overview
I can't install wine32 on my OS:
aydin@kdeneon:~$ uname -a
Linux kdeneon 6.5.0-41-generic #41~22.04.2-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Things I tried
1.
When I try to install it using apt:
aydin@kdeneon:~$ sudo apt install wine32
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) libfaudio0:i386 < none -> 22.02-1 @un puN Ib >
Broken libfaudio0:i386 Depends on libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 < none | 2.0.20+dfsg-2ubuntu1.22.04.1 @un uH > (>= 2.0.16)
  Considering libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 1 as a solution to libfaudio0:i386 0
  Considering libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 1 as a solution to libfaudio0:i386 0
Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libfaudio0:i386 : Depends: libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.0.16) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

2.
I did some research and have tried to install it using aptitude but it did not go well thus I aborted it:
aydin@kdeneon:~$ sudo aptitude install wine32:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  wine32:i386{b} 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  acl{u} gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386{u} hplip-data{u} libapparmor1:i386{u} libasound2:i386{u} libasound2-plugins:i386{u} libasyncns0:i386{u} libatomic1:i386{u} libavahi-client3:i386{u} libavahi-common-data:i386{u} 
  libavahi-common3:i386{u} libcapi20-3:i386{u} libcdparanoia0:i386{u} libcups2:i386{u} libcurl3-gnutls:i386{u} libcurl4:i386{u} libdbus-1-3:i386{u} libdrm2:i386{u} libdw1:i386{u} libedit2:i386{u} libelf1:i386{u} libexif12:i386{u} 
  libflac8:i386{u} libgd3:i386{u} libgdbm-compat4:i386{u} libgdbm6:i386{u} libglapi-mesa:i386{u} libglu1-mesa:i386{u} libglvnd0:i386{u} libgnutls30:i386{u} libgphoto2-6:i386{u} libgphoto2-port12:i386{u} libgsm1:i386{u} 
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386{u} libgstreamer1.0-0:i386{u} libhogweed6:i386{u} libhpmud0{u} libicu70:i386{u} libieee1284-3{u} libieee1284-3:i386{u} libimagequant0{u} libjack-jackd2-0:i386{u} libldap-2.5-0:i386{u} 
  libllvm15:i386{u} libltdl7:i386{u} libnettle8:i386{u} libnghttp2-14:i386{u} libodbc2:i386{u} libogg0:i386{u} libopengl0:i386{u} libopus0:i386{u} liborc-0.4-0:i386{u} libosmesa6:i386{u} libp11-kit0:i386{u} libpcap0.8:i386{u} 
  libpci3:i386{u} libperl5.34:i386{u} libpsl5:i386{u} libpulse0:i386{u} libraqm0{u} librtmp1:i386{u} libsamplerate0:i386{u} libsane-common{u} libsane-hpaio{u} libsane1:i386{u} libsasl2-2:i386{u} libsasl2-modules:i386{u} 
  libsasl2-modules-db:i386{u} libsensors5:i386{u} libsndfile1:i386{u} libsnmp-base{u} libsnmp40{u} libsnmp40:i386{u} libssh-4:i386{u} libtasn1-6:i386{u} libtheora0:i386{u} libunwind8:i386{u} libusb-1.0-0:i386{u} libv4l-0:i386{u} 
  libv4lconvert0:i386{u} libvisual-0.4-0:i386{u} libvorbis0a:i386{u} libvorbisenc2:i386{u} libwayland-client0:i386{u} libwrap0:i386{u} libx11-xcb1:i386{u} libxcomposite1:i386{u} libxcursor1:i386{u} libxfixes3:i386{u} libxi6:i386{u} 
  libxinerama1:i386{u} libxkbcommon0:i386{u} libxkbregistry0:i386{u} libxml2:i386{u} libxpm4:i386{u} libxrandr2:i386{u} libxslt1.1:i386{u} libxxf86vm1:i386{u} ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386{u} printer-driver-hpcups{u} 
  printer-driver-postscript-hp{u} python3-olefile{u} python3-pexpect{u} python3-pil{u} python3-ptyprocess{u} python3-renderpm{u} python3-reportlab{u} python3-reportlab-accel{u} sane-airscan{u} sane-utils:i386{u} wine-stable:i386{u} 
  wine-stable-i386:i386{u} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 112 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
Need to get 229 kB of archives. After unpacking 927 MB will be freed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 6.0.3~repack-1) but it is not installable
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:                                          
1)     libjpeg-turbo8:i386 [2.1.5-2+22.04+jammy+release+build13 (jammy, now)]
2)     libjpeg8:i386 [8c-2ubuntu10 (jammy, now)]                             
3)     libpoppler-glib8:i386 [22.02.0-2ubuntu0.4 (jammy-updates, now)]       
4)     libpoppler118:i386 [22.02.0-2ubuntu0.4 (jammy-updates, now)]          
5)     libtiff5:i386 [4.3.0-6ubuntu0.9 (jammy-security, jammy-updates, now)] 

     Keep the following packages at their current version:                   
6)     wine32:i386 [Not Installed]                                           



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n

3.
I also tried to fix packages using sudo apt --fix-broken install which didn't help.
How you can answer
The best way you can answer is to give an answer to these questions:

Is it recommended to install it using aptitude attentive to what it will remove?
Is there another way that I could install it?
Can I fix the issue with either of the ways I tried?


You are not using Ubuntu but a Ubuntu LIKE OS which is not supported on this Ubuntu support site.

I fixed it by doing: sudo aptitude install wine-stable

I removed your edit to the title. In 48 hours, you will be able to mark your answer as "accepted" and that is the conventional way to note that the matter is resolved. See this help center post but do also note that this is not a Ubuntu question.
